# Hovering over an <option> in a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to show a description when hovering over an option in a select list, however, I am having trouble getting the code to recognize when hovering.

Relevant code:

Select chunk of form:

```
<select name="optionList" id="optionList" onclick="rankFeatures(false)" size="5"></select>
<select name="ranks" id="ranks" size="5"></select>
```

Manipulating selects (arrays defined earlier):

```
function rankFeatures(create) {
    
    var $optionList = $("#optionList");
    var $ranks = $("#ranks");
    
if(create == true) {
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        $optionList.append(features[i]);
    };
}
else {
    var index = $optionList.val();
    $('#optionList option:selected').remove();
    $ranks.append(features[index]);
};
```

}

This all works.  It all falls apart when I try to deal with hovering over options:

```
$(document).ready( 

function (event) {
$('select').hover(function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.is('option')) {
        alert('yeah!');
    };
})
})
```

I found that code while searching through Stack Exchange, yet I am having no luck getting it to work.  The alert occurs when I click on an option. If I don't move the mouse and close the alert by hitting enter, it goes away.  If I close out with the mouse a second alert window pops up.  Just moving the mouse around the select occasionally results in an alert box popping up.

I have tried targeting the options directly, but have had little success with that.  How do I get the alert to pop up if I hover over an option?

Comment: give a sample of early defined array

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/XALuC/ you want that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) event.

And you do not have to use all this code to check if the element is an `option`.

Just use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) syntax to delegate to the `select` element.

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    $('select').on('mouseenter','option',function(e) {
        alert('yeah');
        // this refers to the option so you can do this.value if you need..
    });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/AjfE8/

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work without size="X", on a regular drop-down box.

Answer (score 0):

try with mouseover. Its working for me. Hover also working only when the focus comes out from the optionlist(like mouseout).

```
function (event) {
$('select').mouseover(function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.is('option')) {
        alert('yeah!');
    };
})
})
```

Comment: have a look http://api.jquery.com/hover/. You may need to handle both mouseenter and mouseleave. In your case only mouseleave is working.

Answer (score 0):

That you want is to detect hover event on option element, not on select:

```
$(document).ready( 

    function (event) {
    $('#optionList option').hover(function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
    });
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rap in in a function, I could never get it to work this way. When taking it out works perfect. Also used [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) because [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is ran when leaving the target.

```
$('option').mouseover(function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.is('option')) {
        console.log('yeah!');
    };
})​
```

Fiddle to see it working. Changed it to console so you don't get spammed with alerts. http://jsfiddle.net/HMDqb/

Comment: the wrapping function is DOM ready event. He did very well to wrap it in that.

Comment: Apparently does not work on Chrome when `size` is changed to `1` in your fiddle.  But using `size="2"` seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/o1hxj4nr/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but none of the solutions are working.

```
$("select").on('mouseenter','option',function(e) {
  $("#show-me").show();
});
$("select").on('mouseleave','option',function(e) {
  $("#show-me").hide();
});

$("option").mouseover(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if($target.is('option')) {
    alert('yeah!');
  };
});
```

Here my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ajg99wsm/

Comment: The fiddle does not work on Chrome.  Even after removing the error shown or replacing the code with the one of your answer.  Not tested with something completely different, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go for a customized variant if you like to ease

- capture hover events
- change hover color
- same behavior for "drop down" and "all items" view

plus you can have

- resizeable list
- individual switching between single selection and multiple selection mode
- more individual css-ing
- multiple lines for option items

Just have a look to the sample attached.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.custopt').addClass('liunsel');


  $(".custopt, .custcont").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "crnk") {
      $("#ranks").css("display", "block")
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("lihover");
    }
  })

  $(".custopt, .custcont").on("mouseout", function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "crnk") {
      $("#ranks").css("display", "none")
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("lihover");
    }
  })

  $(".custopt").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".custopt").removeClass("lihover");
    if ($("#btsm").val() == "ssm") {
      //single select mode
      $(".custopt").removeClass("lisel");
      $(".custopt").addClass("liunsel");
      $(this).removeClass("liunsel");
      $(this).addClass("lisel");
    } else if ($("#btsm").val() == "msm") {
      //multiple select mode
      if ($(this).is(".lisel")) {
        $(this).addClass("liunsel");
        $(this).removeClass("lisel");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("lisel");
        $(this).removeClass("liunsel");
      }
    }
    updCustHead();
  });

  $(".custbtn").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "ssm") {
      $(this).val("msm");
      $(this).text("switch to single-select mode")
    } else {
      $(this).val("ssm");
      $(this).text("switch to multi-select mode")
      $(".custopt").removeClass("lisel");
      $(".custopt").addClass("liunsel");
    }
    updCustHead();
  });

  function updCustHead() {
    if ($("#btsm").val() == "ssm") {
      if ($(".lisel").length <= 0) {
        $("#hrnk").text("current selected option");
      } else {
        $("#hrnk").text($(".lisel").text());
      }
    } else {
      var numopt = +$(".lisel").length,
        allopt =  $(".custopt").length;
      $("#hrnk").text(numopt + " of " + allopt + " selected option" + (allopt > 1 || numopt === 0 ? 's' : ''));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.lisel {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.liunsel {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.lihover {
  background-color: coral;
}

.custopt {
  margin: .2em 0 .2em 0;
  padding: .1em .3em .1em .3em;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: .7em;
  border-radius: .4em;
}

.custlist,
.custhead {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .1em;
  border: LightSeaGreen solid .2em;
  border-radius: .4em;
  height: 4em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  resize: vertical;
  user-select: none;
}

.custlist {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custhead {
  resize: none;
  height: 2.2em;
  font-size: .7em;
  padding: .1em .4em .1em .4em;
  margin-bottom: -.2em;
  width: 95%;
}

.custcont {
  width: 7em;
  padding: .5em 1em .6em .5em;
  /* border: blue solid .2em; */
  margin: 1em auto 1em auto;
}

.custbtn {
  font-size: .7em;
  width: 105%;
}

h3 {
  margin: 1em 0 .5em .3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>
  customized selectable, hoverable resizeable dropdown with multi-line, single-selection and multiple-selection support
</h3>
<div id="crnk" class="custcont">
  <div>
    <button id="btsm" class="custbtn" value="ssm">switch to multi-select mode</button>
  </div>
  <div id="hrnk" class="custhead">
    current selected option
  </div>
  <ul id="ranks" class="custlist">
    <li class="custopt">option one</li>
    <li class="custopt">option two</li>
    <li class="custopt">another third long option</li>
    <li class="custopt">another fourth long option</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```