# console.log form option value on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have research questions related to this but couldn't get the solution. What I want to do is to be able to log the option value when I move my mouse over the option. Below is the code that I have right now which is only loging the selected values. I am using google CDN JQuery. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<select>
    <option> value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option> value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Here is JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var select = $("select").children("option");
        $(select).on('mouseover', function(){
            console.log('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't believe that `option` elements raise mouse events reliably - certainly not across all browsers. If you need this behaviour, you would probably be best to use a `select` restyling plugin such as Select2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262653/hovering-over-an-option-in-a-select-list

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I will either use the stackoverflow link provided or use select restyling plugin as suggested by Rory.

Answer (score -1):

You've got a syntax error in your `<select>` element, but I'm hoping that isn't actually going on in your real code.

All I did was target the select element instead of the children and it worked fine.

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var select = $("select")
    $(select).on('mouseover', function () {
        console.log('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: This changes the intended behaviour completely...?