# Hovering Option in Select-field not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hover over option field using jQuery, because I want to call back another JS-function.

I created an easy example on https://jsfiddle.net/ajg99wsm/ to show my problem.

JS:

```
  $("select option").hover(function(){
    $("#show-me").show();
  });
```

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
  <option>Value 3</option>
</select>

 <div id="show-me" style="display:none;">
  This content to show
 </div>
```

What I've noticed, that on 32-Bit Firefox (any version) it is working. On 64-Bit Chrome or Firefox not.

I'm using the current jQuery version and it is mindblowing.
I tried all methods which are used here: [Hovering over an <option> in a select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262653/hovering-over-an-option-in-a-select-list)

Any advice how can I hover through options using jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: I found this as well, but none of them are working.